# How to apply rounding in Excel

Tags: excel, rounding, conditional-operator, rounding-error

I am using this formula to calculate a ratio =(A2/B2)&":"&1, the answer is correct but the answer (1.388888888889:1). How do I reduce the number of decimals to only one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this...

`=ROUND((A2/B2), 1)&":"&1`

Output looks like this....

[image]

Comment: Hi, formula is not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: I used =Round((A2/AB2),1)&":"&1, and it gives an error message.

Comment: Hi @ClarkeO'Donovan - what is the error you are getting? Posted the input/output pic for your reference in the answer